# My logout request for SLO keeps throwing an error saying I should be making an AuthnRequest, not a LogoutRequest

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, saml

I'm attempting to finish building an SSO/SLO bridge. The SSO side works well, but am having issues with the SLO side of things. I've tried using a less robust version of the LogoutRequest but receive the same error so I'm pretty confident the issue is on the side if the IDP, not the SP. Below I've provided most of what I believe is needed. If something else is needed, please let me know.

Here are the sso/slo packages I'm using for my IDP:

- [laravel-samlidp](https://github.com/codegreencreative/laravel-samlidp)
- [lightSAML](https://github.com/lightSAML/lightSAML)

Here is my lightSAML error I keep receiving:

```
Expected 'AuthnRequest' xml node and 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol' namespace but got node 'LogoutRequest' and namespace 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'
```

Here is my Logout Request:

```
<samlp:logoutrequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" id="ONELOGIN_65986ec6f7d2210b9044e24ac739e42bef585bfd" version="2.0" issueinstant="2022-02-22T19:22:09Z" destination="https://my-destination-end-point.com">
<saml:issuer format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" namequalifier="http://sp2.simevo.com:8000">http://requestee-entityId.com</saml:issuer>
<saml:nameid format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">my-user-logging-out@email.com</saml:nameid>
<samlp:sessionindex>_3cf97357196ece9e244a9c2cc678565b8cec659ef6</samlp:sessionindex>
</samlp:logoutrequest>
```

The page being hit is `https://my-destination-end-point.com/logout?SAMLRequest=...`

Comment: Are you definitely logged in when you logout?

Comment: So I guess that may be the problem. I figured samlidp did everything behind the scenes on its own once its posted in the login. It returns to my SP the attributes (full name, email, etc). Is this a sign it is in fact logged in? I can also refresh the laravel page and see that laravel is in fact logged in, so I know the laravel side of it is good.

Comment: Is this a sign it is in fact logged in? Yes.

Comment: @Dom can you help with adding some detail regarding your SSO, I have IDP metadata (Xml) file but did not know what to do with that, where to put that or use in my laravel application can you please guide or help on this.